# Destroy the object in java after certain time

Tags: java

- TTLCache is a special type of cache where users can put objects in the cache with time to live
- The objects should automatically expire after their time to live
- Here is the Test code for the cache
- How can I destroy the object after certain time ?

Here's the stub:

```
public static void testTTLCache() throws Exception {      
  TTLCache cache = null; /* replace with new YourClass() */
  cache.put("key1", "value1", 5);
  cache.put("key2", "value2", 10);

  System.out.println(cache.get("key1")); // should print value1
  System.out.println(cache.get("key2")); // should print value2
  Thread.sleep(1000*6);
  System.out.println(cache.get("key1")); // should print NULL
  System.out.println(cache.get("key2")); // should print value2
  Thread.sleep(1000*6);         
  System.out.println(cache.get("key1")); // should print NULL
  System.out.println(cache.get("key2")); // should print NULL
}
```

Here is its interface on the basis of my requirement, offcourse you can add other method if you need any

```
public interface TTLCache {

    /**
     * @param key - The key to associate with the cache
     * @param value - The actual value to store in the cache
     * @param timeToLiveSeconds - The time to live for this object in the cache
     */
    public void put(String key, Object value, long timeToLiveSeconds);

    /**
     * Returns the Object in the cache that is associated with passed key, or NULL if
     * no value is associated with the key
     * @param key - The key associated with the value to retrieve
     *
     */
    public Object get(String key);

}
```

Comment: What do mean by "destroy the object"?

Comment: Is their any method to destroy the object in java before gc does?

Comment: The garbage collector destroys objects that are no longer used, so setting it to null makes it more likely to be destroyed sooner.

Comment: `cache.remove("key1")` would be an educated guess. You can't expect anything smarter based on the wealth of information you gave here.

Comment: You could replace the direct reference to an object with a WeakReference after the expiration time. That way the object would be around at least until it expired, and then would allow the garbage collector to reclaim it.

Comment: @NathanHughes How to know it is has reached expiration time like 5 seconds is associate with key. Is their anything in java to know it has be 5 second so lets run cache.remove("key1") method

Answer (score 3):

First of all you must distinguish between removing an item from the cache after expiration time and really destroying it.

In Java you don't have control on when an object is effectively destroyed but you just can make objects eligible for destruction and deallocation (by removing any references to them in your code). So if by **destroying** you mean avoiding to return the value if it's expired then you are ok, if by destroying you mean deallocating it then you are out of luck since the only thing you can do is to remove all references and wait for the garbage collector to do its work.

I see two possible solutions for a `TTLCache` implementation:

- keep a running thread which manages the expiration of the objects, when you add a new object save its timestamp and its duration, every thread tick check if there are expired objects and remove them from the cahce
- a lazier approach: don't use a thread, check if an object is still valid only when you try to get it.

For example:

```
void get(String key) {
  if (key is expired) {
    remove key,value from cache;
    return null;
  }
  else
    return value for key;
}
```

Comment: A better way would be to run the checks on `put`---if the cache is overfull, remove something.

Comment: @jack My major problem is how to track time, suppose their is 5 in key 1 which means this object should expire after 5 seconds

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: it depends, if he has a constraint on returning `null` if time is expired then you must manage the situation. If it's enough to just discard older objects when you add new one then working on `put` is enough.

Comment: @bidhutkarki: you must save a timestamp when you add the item to the cache, maybe by using a small wrapper `class CacheEntry { T data; long timestamp; }`and saving `System.nanoTime()` in `timestamp` when you add the item to the cache.

Comment: If you know how caches are supposed to work otherwise, you'll see that a cache doesn't remove anything until it's reached capacity. That's why the best option is to remove at `put`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I know how caches work in general, but this doesn't sound like a normal cache if he has to return invalidated entries when over the expiration time. Check the constraint as the OP posted: __The objects should automatically expire after their time to live__. If you want to answer to your own question about a different kind of cache just open another question, until that point, constraints written by OP are more important than the general concept of cache and inefficiency of removing items when unnecessary. What you say is correct but not regarding this specific question.

Comment: That sentence can be interpreted either way, but the test code does specify unconditional eviction on timeout.

Answer (score 3):

BTW I solve the problem. In case anyone needs it, here it is:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TTL implements TTLCache {

   private HashMap<String, Object[]> cache = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();

    public void put(String key, Object val, long timeToLive) {
        timeToLive = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeToLive * 1000;
        if(key == null) throw new RuntimeException("Key cannot be null!");
        cache.put(key, new Object[]{timeToLive, val});
    }

    public Object get(String key) {

        if (cache.containsKey(key)) {
            Long expires = (Long) cache.get(key)[0];
            if (expires - System.currentTimeMillis() > 0) {
                return cache.get(key)[1];
            } else {
                remove(key);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean remove(Object key) {
        return removeAndGet(key) != null;
    }
   public Object removeAndGet(Object key){
       Object entry = cache.remove(key);
        //System.out.println("entry=" + entry);
        if (entry != null) {
           return entry;
        }
        return null;
}
}
```

Comment: If instead of having a TTL per key you want a fixed TTL for all entries, I've made a small modification to the code of this answer to support that: https://gist.github.com/ulisseslima/71d25cf73954b630fcbc474df2ff251d

Answer (score 2):

A simple, but working, way to do this is to have a `ScheduledExecutorService` and on each `put` you schedule a removing task with the needed delay:

```
scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() { public void run() { 
  cache.remove(key);
}}, timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Note that either the map which backs the cache must be thread-safe, or you must add explicit synchronization.

You must be careful to *cancel* those tasks if a key is reinserted. You must keep a separate map key->`Future`, which allow you to cancel the task.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using HashMap for caching mechanism always use WeakHashMap.